# Regex to match a condition UNLESS it is a hashtag

Tags: python, regex, hashtag

I am trying to write a regex statement to remove digits or words that contain digits in them only if they are not a hashtag. I am able to succesfully match words that have digits in them, but cannot seem to write a condition that ignores words that begin with a hashtag.

Here is a test string that I have been using to try and find a solution:

> happening bit mediacon #2022ppopcon wearing stell naman today #sb19official 123 because h3llo also12 or 23old

I need a regex command that will capture the 123, h3llo, also12 and 23old but ignore the #2022ppopcon and #sb19official strings.

I have tried the following regex statements.

`(#\w+\d+\w*)|(\w+\d+\w*)`
this succesfully captures the hashtags in group 1 and the non-hashtags in group 2, but I cannot figure out how to make it select group 2 only.

`(?<!#)\w*\d+\w*`
this excludes the first character after the hashtag but still captures all the remaining characters in the hashtag string. for example in the string #2022ppopcan, it ignores #2 and captures 022ppopcan.

Comment: It doesn't need to be all regex. You have the rest of Python at your disposal as well. Just check each match to see if it starts with `#` before removing it.

Comment: As I am doing this for a large number of sentences, I would rather not add an extra loop which checks the starting character of each word. I am using re.sub() on the entire sentence. But you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
(?<!\S)[^\W\d]*\d\w*
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `[^\W\d]*` Match optional word chars except a digit
- `\d` Match at least a single digit
- `\w*` Match optional word chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYgyfU/1).

If you want to allow a partial match, you can use a negative lookbehind to not assert a `#` followed by a word boundary:

```
(?<!#)\b[^\W\d]*\d\w*
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sAvNzU/1).

Comment: You are a legend! Both of these regex strings work. Thank you very much. Hopefully I'll get regex figured out soon enough.